# LUKS won't accept password after installing Nvidia GPU driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, keyboard, encryption, luks

I have Ubuntu 18.04.3 running with full disk encryption on my 2014 macbook pro 15. To take advantage of the Nvidia GPU on my computer I decided to install the proprietary Nvidia driver (390) which was tagged as "tested" in the Additional Drivers window (and replace the standard open-source GPU driver provided by Ubuntu). In order to complete the installation I had to restart the computer, but after immediately after I cannot log in because LUKS will no longer accept my password as the correct one.

I assume the keyboard still works as intended because when I interrupt the boot sequence with ESC and type in the grub prompt the keyboard outputs the alphabet and symbols as expected. I have also tried the advice of pressing Caps+Shift+Alt to "reset" the keyboard without success.

Any advice or links that may be useful would be much appreciated.

Edit: Furthermore, I cannot access the encrypted drive through a live usb, it is as if the Nvidia 390 driver changed the password to my LUKS encrypted disk. Is my only option to do a fresh install?

Borrowed picture, but this is the prompt I can't get passed:

[image: Borrowed picture, but same window]

Comment: When you type do any characters appear in the box? Or does it stay completely blank?

Comment: Characters appear in the box. And when I type in grub the symbols appear as expected, e.g. when I press !, that symbol appears on the screen.